# tail a log file but show only specific lines

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm tailing a log file with -f flag. Then I'm piping this to grep, to find only lines that contain "X". That's working perfectly fine.
Now I want to pipe this again into another grep, that will remove all the lines containing "Y". When I add the second pipe, the file stop refreshing and it looks like no data is coming.

This is the command that works:     `tail -f my_file.log | grep "X"`

This is the command that doesn't:   `tail -f my_file.log | grep "X" | grep -v "Y"`

How should I structure this so that the command works?

Comment: try to do one pipe by one pipe, change the sequence, do `tail -f file|grep -v  "Y"` . if the output is ok then proceed to append `grep "X"`.

Comment: [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7161821/995714)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As the output of `grep` is buffered, use `--line-buffered` option of `grep` to enable line buffering:

```
tail -f /path/to/log | grep --line-buffered 'X' | grep -v 'Y'
```

If your `grep` does not have the option, you can use `stdbuf` as an alternative:

```
tail -f /path/to/log | stdbuf -oL grep 'X' | grep -v 'Y'
```

Comment: I am wondering how `stdbuf` tells `libstdbuf.so` which settings to use.

Comment: @kasperd: Environment variables.

Comment: @NateEldredge I already looked for environment variables in the output from `diff -u <(env) <(stdbuf env)` and found none. But now I realize that what I should have tested was `diff -u <(env) <(stdbuf -oL env)`.

Comment: I am also same sort of problem. my case is, I need to print all lines contain 'aaa' and 'bbb'. Above first solution not working. Second solution is working for 'aaa' exist and 'bbb' not exist.  both exist not working. giving no output.  my command looks like this:   `tail -f test.txt | stdbuf -oL grep 'aaa' | grep  'bbb'`  it not giving any output. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 22):

I normally find more useful `awk` for these kind of logical checks:

```
tail -f /path/to/log | awk '/X/ && !/Y/'
#                           ^^^    ^^^^
#                   this I want    but not this
```

Tested by having two tabs, one in which I keep writing `seq 20 >> myfile` and the other one having for example `tail -f myfile | awk '/3/ && !/13/'`.

Answer (score 15):

Another approach would be to use a single `grep` invocation instead of two and so avoid the buffering issue. Just use a regular expressions that matches lines consisting of 0 or more non-Y characters, then an X and then 0 or more non-Ys again till the end of the line"

```
tail -f /path/to/log | grep '^[^Y]*X[^Y]*$'
```